# Read data from excel to table in MATLAB App Designer

Tags: excel, matlab, matlab-gui

Good evening 
I am trying to develop a MATLAB GUI where the user can either input the data manually in a table or attach an excel folder, which will copy the data in the excel sheet in the table. 
My lines of code are

```
function AttachExcelFolderButtonPushed(app, event)
            [filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.xlsx'},'File Selector');
            text = readtable(filename, "Sheet",1);
            app.UITable.Data = text;
        end
```

I get the following error:

Error using readtable (line 223)
Unable to open file 'Book1.xlsx' as a workbook. Check that the file exists, read access is available, and the file is a valid spreadsheet file.

Please help 
Note: I am a newbie 
Thank you

Comment: There is a variable `fullpathname` in your code which is never used.

Comment: I don't think that will produce an error, but thank you for replying, I will remove the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you don't have the file you want on the path. Try this line:

```matlab
text = readtable([pathnaem filename], "Sheet",1);
```

This will use the entire path of the file to find it. Otherwise MATLAB will only look for files currently on the path.

Comment: Thank you very much for replying 
It worked! but it doesn't show the first row and the application window disappears and when I open it again from the desktop bar it shows the values starting the second row

Comment: That has to do with that other attributes in `readtable`. change the line to `text = readtable([pathnaem filename], "Sheet",1, ReadVariableNames',false)` to get the first row. I have no idea what you mean by the other problem.

Comment: It works. thank you so much - I wish I could reply with a small video - When I press "attach excel file," then browse to my documents folder, choose "sheet 1", and double left-click on the file, the screen closes and I have to reopen it from the bottom bar in windows 10, where the table shows and the app runs.

Comment: Sounds strange. Could be a bug. Only thing I can think of to try is:
`waitfor([filename pathname]=uigetfile({'*.xlsx'},'File Selector'));`

Comment: The program tells me:              
Error using app1
Error: File: app1.mlapp Line: 21 Column: 40
Incorrect use of '=' operator. To assign a value to a variable, use '='. To compare values for equality, use '=='.

Comment: I fixed it by putting == instead of = but nothing happens when I press on the "attach excel file" button

Comment: no that wont work, forget the `waitfor`. There is something strange going on. Im not even sure i know what you mean the problem is.

Comment: NVM Thank you so much